# How do you click a button in a browser popup window

Tags: watir

I'm new to using Watir and have a problem. Within my browser page there is an option to add a note. This brings up a window within the browser which has the following id:
**span id="ui-id-2" class="ui-dialog-title">Add Note</span**
I can't work out how to use the controls within this window such as the 'Save' button as Watir doesn't seem to recognise either the window or the controls

So if I wanted to use same type of Save button within the main browser it would be fine; I'd just use **browser.button(:id=> "Save").click**.

Trying to use it within the popup though won't work as Watir can't recognise it within the popup. Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Please provide the full html. My guess is that the object that looks like a button is not actually a button in the DOM. So it'll probably be something like `browser.span(id: 'Save').click`

Comment: Thanks for replying @titusfortner. I'm providing a different example that might clarify the problem. There's a public domain website: https://www.direct.aviva.co.uk/MyAccount/login. At the bottom right of that page there is a button called Questions. If you click it, a popup appears. Within that popup I've tried accessing controls such as the text area for asking questions, but again nothing happens. I just can't work out how to transfer control from the browser to another in-browser window such as the one I'm describing.

Comment: That popup isn't in another window/frame, just navigate to the page and: `driver.find_element(id: 'tcChat_txtInput_input')`